# Linux/Windows app for graphing very large amounts of data

Tags: data-visualization, graphs, data

I'm looking for something that will allow me to graph 50K+ data points on a Cartesian plane, preferably with lots of setting and options for colors, etc.

Note that at this load, LibreOffice crashes.

This doesn't have to work on both Linux and Windows but comparability is a bonus for sure.

---

As it turns out, Microsoft Excel handles 50,000 points quite well, but I haven't found a good way to handle the data on Linux...

Comment: When graphing large numbers of points, the human eye becomes a limiting factor.  Unless your plot size is gigantic, you're probably plotting more points than can be visually distinguished.

Answer (score 2):

On linux, you might find `gnuplot` to be useful.

Comment: GNUplot works on Windows as well.

Answer (score 0):

[GMT](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/) (Generic Mapping Tools) can be used in Linux and Windows and has a very reasonable amount of options/settings for colour etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's Windows only, but I've found Microsoft Power BI Desktop is great for handling and visualizing large quantities. It's pretty flexible with the different data formats it supports.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/desktop/